# Passing arguments to "array-like" container constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, memory-management, initializer-list

### Background

I'm  working with an embedded platform with the following restrictions:

- No heap
- No Boost libraries
- C++11 **is** supported

I've dealt with the following problem a few times in the past:

> Create an array of class type T, where T has no default constructor

The project only recently added C++11 support, and up until now I've been using ad-hoc solutions every time I had to  deal with this. Now that C++11 is available, I thought I'd try to make a more general solution.

### Solution Attempt

I copied [an example of std::aligned_storage](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) to come up with the framework for my array type. The result looks like this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T, size_t N>
class Array {
  // Provide aligned storage for N objects of type T
  typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>::type data[N];

public:
  // Build N objects of type T in the aligned storage using default CTORs
  Array()
  {
    for(auto index = 0; index < N; ++index)
      new(data + index) T();
  }

  const T& operator[](size_t pos) const
  {
    return *reinterpret_cast<const T*>(data + pos);
  }

  // Other methods consistent with std::array API go here
};
```

This is a basic type - `Array<T,N>` only compiles if `T` is default-constructible. I'm not very familiar with template parameter packing, but looking at some examples led me to the following:

```
template<typename ...Args>
Array(Args&&... args) 
{
  for(auto index = 0; index < N; ++index)
    new(data + index) T(args...);
}
```

This was definitely a step in the right direction. `Array<T,N>` now compiles if passed arguments matching a constructor of `T`.

My only remaining problem is constructing an `Array<T,N>` where different elements in the array have different constructor arguments. I figured I could split this into two cases:

#### 1 - User Specifies Arguments

Here's my stab at the CTOR:

```
template<typename U>
Array(std::initializer_list<U> initializers)
{
  // Need to handle mismatch in size between arg and array
  size_t index = 0;
  for(auto arg : initializers) {
    new(data + index) T(arg);
    index++;
  }
}
```

This seems to work fine, aside from needing to handle a dimension mismatch between the array and initializer list, but there are a number of ways to deal with that that aren't important. Here's an example:

```
struct Foo {
  explicit Foo(int i) {}
};

void bar() {
  // foos[0] == Foo(0)
  // foos[1] == Foo(1)
  // ..etc
  Array<Foo,10> foos {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
}
```

#### 2 - Arguments Follow Pattern

In my previous example, `foos` is initialized with an incrementing list, similar to `std::iota`. Ideally I'd like to support something like the following, where `range(int)` returns SOMETHING that can initialize the array.

```
// One of these should initialize foos with parameters returned by range(10)
Array<Foo,10> foosA = range(10);
Array<Foo,10> foosB {range(10)};
Array<Foo,10> foosC = {range(10)};
Array<Foo,10> foosD(range(10));
```

Googling has shown me that `std::initializer_list` isn't a "normal" container, so I don't think there's any way for me to make `range(int)` return a `std::initializer_list` depending on the function parameter.

Again, there are a few options here:

- Parameters specified at run-time (function return?)
- Parameters specified at compile-time (`constexpr` function return? templates?)

### Questions

1. Are there any issues with this solution so far?
2. Does anyone have a suggestion to generate constructor parameters? I can't think of a solution at runtime or compile-time other than hard-coding an `std::initializer_list`, so any ideas are welcome.

Comment: why not use `std:array`? It matches your requirements perfectly

Comment: You could use `vector` with a custom allocator that maps storage to whatever area of storage you have set aside for the purpose

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Can an `std::array` deal with the second initialization type I mentioned? In my example, I could go:

`std::array<Foo,3> = { Foo(0), Foo(1), Foo(2) };`

I don't know how this can be extended though. If I make a function returning `{ Foo(0), Foo(1), Foo(2) }` as an `std::initializer_list<Foo>` and try using it to initialize an `std::array`, I get an error. Can I use an `std::array` without hard-coding all the elements? What if `Foo` isn't copyable?

Comment: @M.M Yeah, I figured that something along those lines would work. I'm not a huge fan of that since the container _should act like an array and not like a vector_. I'd rather not expose the `std::vector` API if the container is meant to be a fixed size with "permanent" (relative to the lifetime of the container) elements.

Comment: @Matt `std::array` don't use `std::initializer_list`, but aggregate initialization, which are different things. For instance, you can have `std::array<std::unique_ptr<int>, 2> myArray{std::make_unique<int>(), std::make_unique<int>()}` and it will build correctly.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I realize the difference between the two - I think the only issues I'm facing are _because_ `std::array` uses aggregate initialization. 

In your example, `myArray` works because `std::make_unique<int>`'s return type matches the element type of `std::array<std::unique_ptr<int>,2>`. This places a few restrictions on `std::array<T,N>`:

1. `T` must be movable or copyable
2. The initializer list can't be returned by a function

I don't think there are workarounds for these issues. If there were, I'd agree that `std::array` is fine for the job.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem correctly, I've also stumbled across std::array's total inflexibility regarding element construction in favor of aggregate initialization (and an absense of statically-allocated container with flexible element contruction options). The best approach I came up with was creating a custom array-like container which accepts **an iterator** to construct it's elements.
This is totally flexible solution:

- Works for both fixed-size and dynamic-sized containers
- Can pass different or same parameters to element constructors
- Can call constructors with one or multiple (tuple piecewise construction) arguments, or even different constructors for different elements (with inversion of control)

For your example it would be like:

```
const size_t SIZE = 10;

std::array<int, SIZE> params;
for (size_t c = 0; c < SIZE; c++) {
    params[c] = c;
}

Array<Foo, SIZE> foos(iterator_construct, &params[0]); //iterator_construct is a special tag to call specific constructor
// also, we are able to pass a pointer as iterator, since it has both increment and dereference operators
```

**Note:** you can totally skip parameters array allocation here by using custom iterator class, which calculates it's value from it's position on-the-fly.

For multiple-argument constructor that would be:

```
const size_t SIZE = 10;

std::array<std::tuple<int, float>, SIZE> params; // will call Foo(int, float)
for (size_t c = 0; c < SIZE; c++) {
    params[c] = std::make_tuple(c, 1.0f);
}

Array<Foo, SIZE> foos(iterator_construct, piecewise_construct, &params[0]);
```

Concrete implementation example is kinda big piece of code, so please let me know if you want more insights into implementation details besides the general idea - I will update my answer then.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a factory lambda.

The lambda takes a pointer to where to construct and an index, and is responsible for constructing.

This makes copy/move easy to write as well, which is a good sign.

```
template<class T, std::size_t N>
struct my_array {
  T* data() { return (T*)&buffer; }
  T const* data() const { return (T const*)&buffer; }

  // basic random-access container operations:
  T* begin() { return data(); }
  T const* begin() const { return data(); }
  T* end() { return data()+N; }
  T const* end() const { return data()+N; }
  T& operator[](std::size_t i){ return *(begin()+i); }
  T const& operator[](std::size_t i)const{ return *(begin()+i); }

  // useful utility:
  bool empty() const { return N!=0; }
  T& front() { return *begin(); }
  T const& front() const { return *begin(); }
  T& back() { return *(end()-1); }
  T const& back() const { return *(end()-1); }
  std::size_t size() const { return N; }

  // construct from function object:
  template<class Factory,
    typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<std::decay_t<Factory>, my_array>::value, int> =0
  >
  my_array( Factory&& factory ) {
    std::size_t i = 0;
    try {
      for(; i < N; ++i) {
        factory( (void*)(data()+i), i );
      }
    } catch(...) {
      // throw during construction.  Unroll creation, and rethrow:
      for(std::size_t j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        (data()+i-j-1)->~T();
      }
      throw;
    }
  }
  // other constructors, in terms of above naturally:
  my_array():
    my_array( [](void* ptr, std::size_t) {
      new(ptr) T();
    } )
  {}
  my_array(my_array&& o):
    my_array( [&](void* ptr, std::size_t i) {
      new(ptr) T( std::move(o[i]) );
    } )
  {}
  my_array(my_array const& o):
    my_array( [&](void* ptr, std::size_t i) {
      new(ptr) T( o[i] );
    } )
  {}
  my_array& operator=(my_array&& o) {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
      (*this)[i] = std::move(o[i]);
    return *this;
  }
  my_array& operator=(my_array const& o) {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
      (*this)[i] = o[i];
    return *this;
  }
private:
  using storage = typename std::aligned_storage< sizeof(T)*N, alignof(T) >::type;
  storage buffer;
};
```

it defines `my_array()`, but that is only compiled if you try to compile it.

Supporting initializer list is relatively easy.  Deciding what to do when the il isn't long enough, or too long, is hard.  I think you might want:

```
template<class Fail>
my_array( std::initializer_list<T> il, Fail&& fail ):
  my_array( [&](void* ptr, std::size_t i) {
    if (i < il.size()) new(ptr) T(il[i]);
    else fail(ptr, i);
  } )
{}
```

which requires you pass in a "what to do on fail".  We could default to throw by adding:

```
template<class WhatToThrow>
struct throw_when_called {
  template<class...Args>
  void operator()(Args&&...)const {
    throw WhatToThrow{"when called"};
  }
};

struct list_too_short:std::length_error {
  list_too_short():std::length_error("list too short") {}
};
template<class Fail=ThrowWhenCalled<list_too_short>>
my_array( std::initializer_list<T> il, Fail&& fail={} ):
  my_array( [&](void* ptr, std::size_t i) {
    if (i < il.size()) new(ptr) T(il[i]);
    else fail(ptr, i);
  } )
{}
```

which if I wrote it right, makes a too-short initializer list cause a meaningful throw message.  On your platform, you could just `exit(-1)` if you don't have exceptions.